# Android visualize PCM data with JTransform library

Tags: android, audio, fft, visualization

I am trying to display some visualization effect of some PCM data.
The target is to display something like the following:

[image]

I searched and found that JTransform is the correct library to use. However, I cannot find a good guide of how to use this library. How can I translate my PCM data into the band/frequency data that can be used to draw the bars?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever get a working example of this? I am trying to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCM audio is the digitized simplification of an analog audio curve ... this time domain signal can get feed into a Discrete Fourier Transform api call to transform the data into its frequency domain equivalent ...  imaginary numbers and Euler's Formula are your friends

The easy part is to call fft, its more involved to parse its output ...
fill a buffer with at least 1024 (make sure its a power of 2) points from your PCM and just feed this into some fft api call ... this will return back to you its frequency domain equivalent ... nail the doc on whichever Discrete Fourier Transform api call you use ... lookup notion of Nyquist Limit ... master idea of frequency bin ... keep at hand number of samples per buffer and sample rate of your PCM audio

Be aware as you increase the number of audio samples (PCM points on the audio curve) you feed into a Fourier Transform the finer the frequency resolution returned from that call, however if your audio is some dynamic signal like music (opposed to a static tone) this lowers the temporal specificity

Here is a function I wrote in golang which is a wrapper around a call to DFT where I feed it a PCM raw audio buffer normalized into floating point which varies from -1 to +1 where it makes the Discrete Fourier Transform (fft) call then calculates magnitude of each frequency bin using array of complex numbers returned from DFT ... a portion of a project which synthesizes audio by watching video (an image at a time) then it can listen to that audio to synthesize output images ... achieved goal where output photo largely matches input photo ...... input image -> audio -> output image

```
func discrete_time_fourier_transform(aperiodic_audio_wave []float64, flow_data_spec *Flow_Spec) ([]discrete_fft, float64, float64, []float64) {

    min_freq := flow_data_spec.min_freq
    max_freq := flow_data_spec.max_freq

    //      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGsMWi_j4Q
    //      Discrete Fourier Transform - Simple Step by Step 

    var complex_fft []complex128

    complex_fft = fft.FFTReal(aperiodic_audio_wave) // input time domain ... output frequency domain of equally spaced freqs

    number_of_samples := float64(len(complex_fft))

    nyquist_limit_index := int(number_of_samples / 2)

    all_dft := make([]discrete_fft, 0) // 20171008

    /*
       0th term of complex_fft is sum of all other terms
       often called the bias shift
    */

    var curr_real, curr_imag, curr_mag, curr_theta, max_magnitude, min_magnitude float64

    max_magnitude = -999.0
    min_magnitude = 999.0
    min_magnitude = 999.0

    all_magnitudes := make([]float64, 0)

    curr_freq := 0.0
    incr_freq := flow_data_spec.sample_rate / number_of_samples

    for index, curr_complex := range complex_fft { // we really only use half this range + 1

        // if index <= nyquist_limit_index {
        if index <= nyquist_limit_index && curr_freq >= min_freq && curr_freq < max_freq {

            curr_real = real(curr_complex) // pluck out real portion of imaginary number
            curr_imag = imag(curr_complex) // ditto for im

            curr_mag = 2.0 * math.Sqrt(curr_real*curr_real+curr_imag*curr_imag) / number_of_samples

            curr_theta = math.Atan2(curr_imag, curr_real)

            curr_dftt := discrete_fft{

                real:      2.0 * curr_real,
                imaginary: 2.0 * curr_imag,
                magnitude: curr_mag,
                theta:     curr_theta,
            }

            if curr_dftt.magnitude > max_magnitude {

                max_magnitude = curr_dftt.magnitude
            }

            if curr_dftt.magnitude < min_magnitude {

                min_magnitude = curr_dftt.magnitude
            }

            // ... now stow it

            all_dft = append(all_dft, curr_dftt) 

            all_magnitudes = append(all_magnitudes, curr_mag)
        }

        curr_freq += incr_freq
    }

    return all_dft, max_magnitude, min_magnitude, all_magnitudes
}
```

Now you have an array all_magnitudes where each element of the array is the magnitude of that frequency bin ... each frequency bin is evenly spaced by a frequency increment defined by above var incr_freq ... normalize the magnitude using min and max_magnitude ... its ready to feed into an X,Y plot to give you the spectrogram visualization

I suggest cracking open some books ... watch the video I mention in above comments ... my voyage of exploration into wonders of the Fourier Transform has been ongoing since being an EE undergrad and its loaded with surprising applications and its theory continues to be a very active research domain